# Can I issue a command when a specific message issued in the syslog

Tags: usb-power, usb-hub

I am having power problems with my USB devices which is proving difficult to resolve. However I can see on the syslog that there is a specific error message which shows there is a problem. What I would like to do, as a temporary measure, is issue a command to restart the service when this message is issued.

Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Comment: This is not a Pi specific question.  The same answers apply to any Linux machine.  Perhaps look at the `tail` and `grep` commands.

Comment: @joan: Assuming that switching the USB driver off then on is a reasonable approach to the user's issue, do you feel that there are no diffs between RPi, and "other distros" and hardware to bring this question back under the RPi umbrella?

Comment: @Seamus If that was what was being asked, yes.  However that isn't the question as I read it.